# Creating an Array to store Table Cell Button Values at Cell Index

Tags: ios, swift, logic

I am currently working on a program where I have a TableView with a Segmented Control in each row. I have attached a tag to each segmented control that corresponds to the row the segmented control is in (i.e. segmented control 1 corresponds to row 1, etc). Additionally, the segmented control has its own index (option 0 corresponds to an index of 0 and option 1 corresponds to an index of 1)

I would like to have an array that stores the value of the segmented control index in a location that corresponds to segmented control's tag. i.e. if the first row's segmented control index is 1, the second row's segmented control index is 0, and the third row's segmented control index is 1, the array should output:
[1,0,1]

The best idea I have is to create an array, specify the array's index as the segmented control's tag, and then specify the value at that index to be the value of the segmented control's index (sorry I know its confusing).

I'm sure this is a programming problem someone has had before, however I can't find any information on it. I am programming in swift, but since this is more of a logical problem than a programming one I am willing to accept a solution in any other language.

Thanks,
Nick

P.S.
Here is a picture of the app so far and the code I am using for your reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezMUJ.png

import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return 10
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)


    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Sample Item"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let actionButton = YSSegmentedControl(
        frame: CGRect.zero,
        titles: [
            "Yes",
            "No"
        ])


actionButton.delegate = self
cell.addSubview(nameLabel)
cell.addSubview(actionButton)
actionButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]-160-[v1]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel, "v1": actionButton]));
cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel]))
cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-60-[v0]-60-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": actionButton]))

actionButton.tag = indexPath.row


    cell.backgroundColor = .green
    return cell

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}

extension MyTableViewController: YSSegmentedControlDelegate {
func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt    index: Int) {
    print("\(segmentedControl.tag)" + "\(index)")

}

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, didPressItemAt index: Int) {

}
```

}

Comment: Is your goal to have 10 generic rows or will there eventually be a datasource for the table? The reason I ask is because if you eventually plan on having a datasource to populate the table then that would be the best place to store your values. Maintaining separate data arrays usually causes more trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a dictionary instead of an array? This way ou can store and easily look up the segment control's index from it's tag or vice versa:

```
// Storing index and corresponding tag
var indexToTag = [Int:Int]()
indexToTag[index] = tag

// Looking up tag
let tag = indexToTag[index]
```

You can also do the opposite:

```
// Storing tag and corresponding index
var tagToIndex = [Int:Int]()
tagToIndex[tag] = index

// Looking up tag
let index = tagToIndex[tag]
```

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but you could even store an array of you `UISegmentedControls` so you could reference them by `indexRow.path` and get whatever info you want:

```
var mySegments = [UISegmentedControls]()
```

You can even use them in a dictionary

```
var tagToSegment = [Int:UISegmentedControls]()
```

Comment: Storing an array of UISegmentedControls would not be a good idea because of cell reuse.

Comment: I like the dictionary Idea. I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work though, only one key/value is being added to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array like will work as long as the number of items in the array matches the number of cells. So in you table view controller you have an array which is populated with the initial values.  Something like this:

```
var dataArray: [Int] = [1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
```

You can then use the array to determine the number of rows you require so that they always match like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return dataArray.count
}
```

The basic idea is to separate out the data representation from the UI.

On a related note and to help you out you have a problem when creating the cell.  You use dequeueReusableCell to get a cell from the table and then add your label and segmented control to it.  When the table scrolls the cells will begin to be reused and you will get one you have already added the label and segmented control to and you will add another label and segmented control to it.  This will continue on and on until you have loads of labels and segment controls on each cell.  You need to avoid doing this otherwise eventually your app may crash.